# Find a unexpected error from printf with format of %.1f for rounding digital?

Tags: c++, printf, rounding

When I compile and run the C++ code using g++5.4.0/dev C++ 5.11 , the answer is unexpected. Can somebody help me？

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     double b = 36.25;
     printf("%.1f\n", b);
     return 0;
}
```

The running result is： **36.2**, 
which is not the preferred result of **36.3** for rounding the digits 36.25.

help！！Thanks！！

Comment: @usr2564301: The C++ standard defers to the C standard for the behavior of `printf`. The C standard says, for the `f` conversion specifier, “The value is rounded to the appropriate number of digits.”

Comment: Try 36.75 instead of 36.25. Do you get “36.8”? I do with LLVM 9.0.0, clang-900.0.39.2 on macOS 10.13.2, so I expect the rounding rule its library is using is to round ties to an even digit. g++ may be doing the same. The C standard specifies methods to change the rounding method in `fenv.h`, but g++ 5.4 does not support them, so I do not expect you will be able to change how the library does rounding. You would have to manually calculate the result you want, then print that.

Comment: I do not have GCC 5.4 on hand, but testing GCC 5.3 and 6.3 with online (web-interface) compilers confirms that 36.25 produces 36.2 and 36.75 produces 36.8, so GCC 5.4 is almost certainly using the rounding rule of producing the nearest value and, in case of tie, choosing the even digit.

Answer (score 1):

No,Your code work properly this is the rule.

Well,round figure output of 36.25 is also 36.2 because

- > In rounding off numbers, if the first figure dropped is 5, and all
  >   the figures following the five are zero or if there are no figures
  >   after the 5, then the last figure kept should be unchanged if that
  >   last figure is even. For example, if only one decimal is to be kept,
  >   then 6.6500 becomes 6.6.

For more information visit http://academic.brooklyn.cuny.edu/geology/leveson/core/linksa/roundoff.html

So,the result is also 36.2 know if you change the test case for example 36.75

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     double b = 36.75;
     printf("%.1f\n", b);
     return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
36.8
```

Now,Second case is if after 5 value is not eqal zero

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    double i=36.252;
        printf("%.1f",i);
        return 0;
}
```

As expected output is

```
36.3
```

I think this one will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I run this code as following: 
int main()
{ 
  double a = 36.2; 
  printf("%.1f\n", a); 
  double b = 36.225; 
  printf("%.2f\n", b); 
  double c = 36.2225; 
  printf("%.3f\n", c); 
  return 0; 
} 
the results is 36.2, 36.23 and 36.222 respectively. 
The first and last are round to floor, and the second is round to ceiling. 
It look doesn't hold the last figure to even. This rounding rule is entirely confused me.

Comment: No, value is not round to floor or ceil. This is  maths rule that if there is no any digit after a value less then 5 then it is not going to be round.For once you visit and read the rules carefully http://academic.brooklyn.cuny.edu/geology/leveson/core/linksa/roundoff.html